# Consecutive statements error. trying to write root view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am following a tutorial on multi view applications and it's trying to get me to write the root  view controller. I put in the exact code they gave but I am getting a consecutive statements error on one line. Here is my code:

```
blueViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(" Blue") as BlueViewController blueViewController.view.frame = view.frame switchViewController( from: nil, to: blueViewController)
```

Comment: Looks like you just need some linebreaks between the different statements. ex. the first one should come after `as BlueViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
blueViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(" Blue") as BlueViewController 
blueViewController.view.frame = view.frame 
switchViewController( from: nil, to: blueViewController)
```